# User script installation

Tags: browser, userscripts

Is it possible to make it so I can put the user script that I made on my website and users to instal it simply by clicking on it (on firefox and chrome)?
And if it is possible how do I do it?

And how do I put my user script in chrome manually? In firefox it is simple, I just click on greasemonkey icon and select "new user script". But I simply can't figure out how to do it in chrome and couldn't find the answer online.

For me this looks like a really simple thing to do, but from some reason I can't find the answer by googling. Am I using a bad key word or something? idk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make it so I can put the user script that I made on
>   my website and users to instal it simply by clicking on it (on firefox
>   and chrome)? And if it is possible how do I do it?

Yes. Just insert an ordinary download link such as

`<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/script/yourscript.user.js">Click here to download my script!</a>`.

Please note prospective users should have Greasemonkey (Firefox) or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Chrome) installed. Also, filename of the script should end with `.user.js`.

[Example](http://www.danielslaughter.com/projects/gmail-pop3-checker-for-greasemonkey/)

> And how do I put my user script in chrome manually? In firefox it is
>   simple, I just click on greasemonkey icon and select "new user
>   script". But I simply can't figure out how to do it in chrome and
>   couldn't find the answer online.

[Use Tampermonkey.](http://tampermonkey.net/faq.php#Q102)

Comment: the problem was that I was using .js instead of .user.js but I found the answer elsewhere and forgot to say that here. thanks anyway